# SQL 2 different comment types - best solution?

Tags: database-design

I have a database in which users can post comments on news or pictures.
What is the best solution to do this?
I have come up with 3 variants

First one:

```
Comments
- id (PK)
- userID
- timestamp
- text
- newsID (FK News, can be NULL)
- pictureID (FK Picture, can be NULL)
```

Second one:

```
Comments
- id (PK)
- userID
- timestamp
- text

News_Comments
- newsID (PK, FK News)
- commentID (PK, FK Comment)

Picture_Comments
- pictureID (PK, FK Picture)
- commentID (PK, FK Comment)
```

Third one:

```
News_Comments
- id (PK)
- newsID (FK News)
- userID
- timestamp
- text

Picture_Comments
- id (PK)
- pictureID (FK Picture)
- userID
- timestamp
- text
```

Comment: This will probably be closed as too broad/opinion based.

Comment: @dfundako: It shouldn't. This is a very precise question on database design and a rather common question at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rule out variant 2, because it suggests n:m relations, which is not what you are after.

Variants 1 and 2 both look fine and it's mainly a matter of personal preference which to choose.

With variant 1 you'd argue that both are comments and if at one time you also want to record a vote along with each comment, you just add a vote column to that table.

With variant 3 you'd argue that the two are comments on different things and if at one time you also want to have votes for grammar and writing style, you'd add appropriate columns to the news comment table only, whereas in the picture comments table you may have a vote column for artistry.

As said, it's partly a personal preference, but it's also about what you think what these tables may look like in the distant future :-)

---

In the 3rd variant you should remove `commentID (PK, FK Comment)` from the tables, as there is no comment table. The tables should have an ID of their own (e.g. `news_comment_id (PK)`) and `newsid` and `pictureid` would be mere foreign keys and no longer be part of the primary key.

Comment: Oops that was a mistake. Of course, the third variant should be as described by you. I edited it.